# How to fix 'php_redis.dll load failed , %1 is not a valid Win32 application' error on windows

Tags: phpredis

I  added

> php_redis.dll file in /php/ext folder

and added

> extension=redis in php.ini  file.

I am using 64bit xampp server on windows 10. This is what I see in the error log:

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_redis.dll'
>   (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_redis.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32
>   application.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_redis.dll.dll (The specified
>   module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Anyone faced similar issues? Do we have a working solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add something that you have tried so that the community can help you.

Comment: @Mrugaya did this solved ?? whats exactly issues there??
I facing the same issues

Answer (score 0):

Okey guys, i have same errors and do some tests))

i have only x86 based solution, i use this for my web devel, worked 100% on Windows 10 x64, so

1. Download and install Redis 3.2.100 x64 for Windows, (or latest https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases/), with this link:
   https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases/download/win-3.2.100/Redis-x64-3.2.100.msi
2. Check and save in text file your version of PHP with PHPInfo and additional info: VC14 or VC15, x86 or x64, Thread Safe or Not Thread Safe - you may check with this command: php -i|findstr "Thread" - if enabled you use TS version.

If you not have installed PHP download and unpack (install) PHP v7.3.25 NTS Win32 VC15 x86, with this link:
https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-7.3.25-nts-Win32-VC15-x86.zip

3. Download Redis v5.1.1 for PHP 7.3 NTS VC15 x86, (or latest https://pecl.php.net/package/redis click on DLL and choose needed version PHP 7.x and check TS or NTS version) or use this link:
   https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/redis/5.1.1/php_redis-5.1.1-7.3-nts-vc15-x86.zip
4. Create dir with small symbols:

   C:\php\ext
5. Unpack php_redis-5.1.1-7.3-nts-vc15-x86.zip archive and copy two files to C:\php\ext directory:

   php_redis.dll

   php_redis.pdb
6. Edit your php.ini in PHP dir:
   search & edit your "Paths and Directories" section, like that:

   ;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"

   ;http://php.net/include-path

   ;extension_dir =

   doc_root =

   user_dir =

also search & edit your "Dynamic Extensions" section, add line:

extension=php_redis.dll

7. Run web server and test your PHPInfo, you need to see Redis extension section!